# vba error when using IndexMatch and two Criteria with Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, index-match

I am looking for a code to use an index match formula with 2 criteria. Index data is on sheet "cpk_mola_pivot" in pivot table called "cpk_mola_pivottable". 
Results to be returned are in the pivot table column 3. 
 Criteria 1 is on source sheet "comparison report" in Column J starting row 3 to last row. Criteria 1 is matched to Column A in the pivot table. Criteria 2 is fixed in cell $O$2. 
 Criteria 2 is matched to Column B in the pivot table. Results to be populated O3 to last row in the source sheet "comparison report".

When I run the code I am getting an object required at the resultsrange code line even though I specified the pivottable.

```
sub cpkMola_indexmatch2

    Dim wsComparisonReport As Worksheet
    Dim wsCPK_Mola_Pivot As Worksheet
    Dim mypivotTable As pivotTable
    Dim lastRowComparison As Long, lastRowPivot As Long
    Dim criteria1 As Range, criteria2 As Variant
    Dim resultRange As Range
    Dim i As Long

' Set the references to the worksheets
    Set wsComparisonReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("comparison report")
    Set wsCPK_Mola_Pivot = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("cpk_mola_pivot")

' Set the reference to the pivot table
    Set mypivotTable = wsCPK_Mola_Pivot.PivotTables("cpk_mola_pivottable")

' Find the last rows in the Comparison Report and Pivot Table sheets
    lastRowComparison = wsComparisonReport.Cells(wsComparisonReport.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowPivot = wsCPK_Mola_Pivot.Cells(wsCPK_Mola_Pivot.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Set the ranges for Criteria 1 and Criteria 2
    Set criteria1 = wsComparisonReport.Range("J3:J" & lastRowComparison)
    criteria2 = wsComparisonReport.Range("$O$2").value

' Set the result range in the Comparison Report sheet
    Set resultRange = wsComparisonReport.Range("O3:O" & lastRowComparison)

' Loop through each row in the Comparison Report sheet and use Index-Match to populate the results
    For i = 1 To criteria1.Rows.Count
        resultRange.Cells(i, 1).value = Application.Index(mypivotTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Resize(, 3), _
        Application.Match(criteria1.Cells(i, 1).value, mypivotTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1), 0), _
        Application.Match(criteria2.value, mypivotTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(2), 0))
    Next i
End Sub
```

sample of results in pivot
[image]

sample of sheet "comparison report"
[image]

Comment: `criteria2` is not an object and does not have a `.Value` property.

Comment: i changed Criteria2 to range and the code to:     Set criteria2 = wsComparisonReport.Range("$O$2"). But now i am getting N/A as populated results.

Comment: Sounds like one or both of the `Match` instances aren't finding a match?

Comment: This may relate to the pivottable layout. A screenshot would help determine if that is the cause.

Comment: i updated with some screenshots. I added the code line  Print the value of criteria1 in the Immediate window
    Debug.Print "Value of criteria1: " & criteria1.Address to find out what the value is of criteria1 and it is the entire range in column J. J3:J17 which is probably the reason ATL-AMS is not getting a match.

Comment: INDEX does not allow two vertical matches.  The first match would return the Row and the second would return the column.  You are trying to return two rows.  The best thing here would be to iterate the rows in the pivot table and find where each column matches and return the value when both match.

Comment: that s right. didn't think of that. In Excel you can write the formula Index(match(1,(column=criteria1)*(column=criteria2). But i am not sure how to code that. So your suggestion would be a if criteria 1 = true then if criteria 2 = true then return value from column 3? any suggestion on "if then code loop"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub vlookupwith2criteria()

Dim comparisonSheet As Worksheet
Dim pivotSheet As Worksheet
Dim comparisonData As Variant
Dim pivotData As Variant
Dim comparisonLastRow As Long
Dim pivotLastRow As Long
Dim criteria1Range As Range
Dim criteria2Ranges As Variant
Dim outputRanges As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim criteria1 As String, criteria2 As String
Dim matchFound As Boolean

' Set the sheet references
Set comparisonSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("comparison")
Set pivotSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("datapivot")

' Find the last rows in both sheets
comparisonLastRow = comparisonSheet.Cells(comparisonSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
pivotLastRow = pivotSheet.Cells(pivotSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Load data into variant arrays for faster processing
comparisonData = comparisonSheet.Range("A3:C" & comparisonLastRow).value
pivotData = pivotSheet.Range("A1:C" & pivotLastRow).value

' Define the criteria2 and output ranges using arrays
criteria2Ranges = Array(comparisonSheet.Range("$O$2").value, comparisonSheet.Range("$P$2").value, comparisonSheet.Range("$Q$2").value)
outputRanges = Array(comparisonSheet.Range("O3:O" & comparisonLastRow), comparisonSheet.Range("P3:P" & comparisonLastRow), comparisonSheet.Range("Q3:Q" & comparisonLastRow))

' Loop through each month (3 iterations)
For monthIndex = 1 To 3
    Set criteria1Range = comparisonSheet.Range("J3:J" & comparisonLastRow)

    ' Loop through each row in the comparison sheet
    For i = 1 To comparisonLastRow - 2 ' Subtract 2 because the data starts from row 3
        criteria1 = criteria1Range.Cells(i).value
        criteria2 = criteria2Ranges(monthIndex - 1) ' monthIndex - 1 to access the correct criteria2 for the current month
        matchFound = False

        ' Loop through each row in the pivot sheet to find a match for criteria 1 and criteria 2
        For j = 1 To pivotLastRow
            If pivotData(j, 1) = criteria1 And pivotData(j, 2) = criteria2 Then
                ' Match found, populate the value from Column C on the comparison sheet
                outputRanges(monthIndex - 1).Cells(i).value = pivotData(j, 3)
                matchFound = True
                Exit For ' Exit the loop once a match is found
            End If
        Next j

        ' If no match is found for criteria 1 and criteria 2, clear the output cell
        If Not matchFound Then
            outputRanges(monthIndex - 1).Cells(i).value = ""
        End If
    Next i
Next monthIndex

' Clear the memory for the variant arrays
Erase comparisonData
Erase pivotData
```

End Sub